# Kotlin: unit test assert object after gson

Tags: junit, gson, kotlin

I have JUnit test like that:

```
Test fun testCategoriesLoading() {
    val subscriber = TestSubscriber<List<ACategory>>()
    service.categories().subscribe(subscriber)

    subscriber.awaitTerminalEvent()

    subscriber.assertNoErrors()
}
```

service is [Retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/), that uses GsonConverter to deserialize json into

```
data class ACategory(val id: String, val title: String, val parentId: String?, val hasChildren: Boolean)
```

instances.

Test is passing, even if ACategory filled with id = null, title = null etc.

So, as far as i know, gson using reflection, and kotlin lazily resolves this nullability constraints on first access.

Is there any way to force this resolve?
Some good-looking solution without direct access to fields manually? I really don't want to write every assert by hand.

Comment: As far as I remember Gson injects field values directly to the fields without constructor call so Kotlin can't verify it because even constructor is not called at all. It is done by true black magic inside gson. See example: https://gist.github.com/cy6erGn0m/4decafcb06baeb4f2e3b

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the new Kotlin reflection. If you have an instance of `ACategory`, call

```
ACategory::class.memberProperties
        .filter { !it.returnType.isMarkedNullable }
        .forEach {
            assertNotNull(it.get(aCategory))
        }
```

to access all properties that are marked as not nullable and assert they're not null. Make sure, you have the reflection lib on the classpath.

Make sure you're using M14.

Comment: this is the first thing we did... it prints "null" even for non-nullable property :(

Comment: @ntoskrnl gson knows nothing about you declare type as not-nullable. I got a bunch of NPE at the beginning. To avoid confusion mark fields as nullable

Comment: @ruX we couldn't find a universal way to check if the data were parsed correctly and all required (i.e. non-nullable) fields were set. For data classes, calling `copy()` does what we want – throws an exception if at least one required field is null. The question is how to achieve this for non-data classes...

Comment: I updated the answer. You can not check if a property's return type is not nullable. Use this to get all non-nullable properties and assert they're not null.

Comment: The previous comment was probably meant to say "you can **now** check if a property's return type is not nullable."

Answer (score 0):

We ended up with hack for data classes(only use case for us, so its ok).

Calling `gsonConstructedObject.copy()` reveals all exceptions

Comment: The answer is cleaner from @cypressious, and allows you to more intentionally report an error for the property instead of just NPE.

Comment: @JaysonMinard, agree, edited version is better than our hacky way. (changed chosen answer)

Comment: Great, and its good to have this alternative which basically causes the object to recreate itself and validate its own parameters.  good hack